# Building Rust gstreamer plugins

Tags: rust, gstreamer, rust-cargo

Im trying to build Gstreamer rust plugins in docker, During cargo build im facing this error, where it says 'gstreamer' package is not found, but just checked the gitlab location where it searched, it does have gstreamer package and cargo.toml file also seems right. Refer: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/main/gstreamer/Cargo.toml?ref_type=heads

```
Updating crates.io index
Updating git repository `https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs`
Updating git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir`
Updating git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir-files`
Updating git submodule `https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gir-files-rs.git`
Updating git repository `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core`
Updating git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir`
Updating git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir-files`
Updating git repository `https://github.com/rust-av/flavors`
Updating git repository `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs`
Updating git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir`
Updating git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir-files`
Updating git repository `https://github.com/rust-av/ffv1.git`
error: no matching package named `gstreamer` found
location searched: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs
required by package `gst-plugin-tutorial v0.12.0-alpha.1 (/usr/src/gst-plugins- rs/tutorial)`
```

Comment: What is the crate `gst-plugin-tutorial`? What does your Cargo.toml look like?

Comment: @drewtato This is the docker file Im running https://github.com/Kynothon/gst-plugins-rs-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.arch

Comment: The Cargo.toml is here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/blob/245185d2f68a10da3834140175f56f280342f47e/tutorial/Cargo.toml I'm guessing you uncommented the line for `--package gst-plugin-tutorial`? I don't see anything weird on the rust side.